# Angular 8 - Typing indicator from websocket

Tags: angular, date, typing, indicator

I'm currently working on web chat in Angular 8. I am connected to websocket, and I'm receiving information about that someone is typing a message. It is called "Typing indicator". I get this information everytime someone is typing something to me. Unfortunately, I'm not receiving information that someone has stopped typing, and I need to implement logic, that if someone has stopped typing, I'm showing typing indicator for only 4 seconds long.

```
public showTypingIndicator() {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  currentDate.setSeconds(currentDate.getSeconds() - 4);

  return this.lastTypingDate !== null && this.lastTypingDate > currentDate;
}
```

My `this.lastTypingDate` I get from my service in case in my websocket I received a message with type "Typing-indicator", and then I set this to `this.lastTypingDate = new Date();`. This is how I pass data to this variable from my service: `this.myDateService.getLastTypingDate()`.

This works, but it is showing my typing indicator for longer time than 4 seconds. Any thoughts what can be changed here to make it works as expected?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you add some more code to understand context like when `lastTypingDate` is set?

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. I edited my question and provided more information.

Comment: Can you add some more code? maybe a stackblitz example? 
It's harder to provide solution with only method.
When `showTypingIndicator` gets called? How many times it gets called?

Comment: My `showTypingIndicator` method is called in my HTML of this component: `*ngIf="showTypingIndicator()"` and it gets called only once. I think it will be hard to prepare a stacblitz for this, but I will try :)

Comment: You answered you own question, I think - It only gets called once. You need to call it with every new event from the websocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by using rxjs and `BehaviorSubject`.
I'm passing value to `BehaviorSubject` to true, only when subscription receives some data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change `showTypingIndicator` function to getter and compare dates in seconds.

```
public get showTypingIndicator() {
    const currentSeconds = (new Date()).getTime()/1000;
    return !!this.lastTypingDate && (currentSeconds - (this.lastTypingDate.getTime()/1000)) < 5;
}
```

Whenever your service updates `lastTypingDate`, `showTypingIndicator` gets evaluated. With function, you need to call every time.

Comment: I am subscribed to the method which is populating this variable `lastTypingDate` anytime websocket respond with this type of message. In switch case statement I'm checking if there is this type of message.
I have tried your code, but I receive an error:
`Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined`.

Comment: Can you try this with `!!this.lastTypingDate && ...`
updated my answer

Comment: Still no luck with that. I can't see typing indicator now at all.

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz